# Zoom in and rotate simultaneously on seekbar in Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I am working on a project where I need to ZoomIn and rotate the image simultaneously on seekbar progress value.

I have tried below code. But this is not working. This is just rotating the image.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(curValue);
//matrix.postScale(curValue, curValue);
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmaprotate, 0, 0, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, matrix, true);
mainImage.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```

Comment: http://nineoldandroids.com/
https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids
pls see this,you may get something related to this

Comment: See the answer below about using a Canvas in the draw method of a custom View. You definitely **do not** want to create new bitmaps in this manner when transforming the image for display is your goal. Your transformed image only needs to exist in a temporary drawing buffer, not autonomously in memory.

Answer (score 2):

For achieving this you better to use custom view and canvas. Using canvas you can easily rotate and scale the images. Please refer this links ([resize the bitmap canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426025/resize-the-bitmap-canvas) ,[Android Scaling Canvas Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925915/android-scaling-canvas-bitmap) , http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-simple-2d-graphics-part-1/)